# xcode 4: apps performance is affected by odd crash (debugger useless)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, performance

I am writing a side scrolling game app and am nearing the finish but out of nowhere this crash started happening almost every time I run now. I am debugging on a 4th gen Ipod touch.

The graphics will begin to lag and then my player movement will glitch and my player velocity will get stuck at a random speed. I receive no memory warnings and the game keeps on being playable despite the player speed being stuck. It does not exit out of the app.

Using the debugger has got me nowhere because it doesn't register with the debugger as anything going wrong. I guess it doesn't throw an exception.

I began watching the Device logs as I run the app and the lag starts to begin as im getting errors and warnings in device logs about:

```
ReportCrash[456] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process AdSheet[454]
Sep 23 18:49:33  com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.AdSheetPhone[0xb005]) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6
Sep 23 18:49:33  backboardd[26] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.apple.AdSheetPhone[0xb005]' exited abnormally with signal 6: Abort trap: 6
Sep 23 18:49:33  ReportCrash[456] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Sep 23 18:49:33  ReportCrash[456] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/AdSheet_2013-09-23-184932_Carla-Passs-iPod.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

In the crash report it says it is a SIGABRT type crash but again I can't trace it back to any source code because the debugger doesnt recognize anything wrong.. Also I have no warning in my source code.

Any help would be much appreciated. Also i have the crash report if anyone wants to look at that hideous document.

Comment: Can you include the crash report in your post?

Comment: Can you state your question more clearly?